# Command to delete all files and folders in a folder using ncftp

Tags: ftp, windows-server

I have a folder on a remote server that I need cleared. I need all files and folders in this folder deleted. I cannot delete and recreate the parent folder because I don't want to mess up the permissions.

For example:
Remote folder is Development/
That folder contains several files and several folders.
I want to run a command to completely empty the Development/ folder and leave me a fresh empty version.

I also need this to be compatible with a Windows FTP client.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use ncftp, or will any ftp program suffice?

Comment: I'm actually using it for a TeamCity build, so any compatible FTP alternative would be great.

Answer (score 6):

Since you clarified that you aren't limited to ncftp, you should use [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) instead which has built-in support for operations like that using `glob` and `rm -r`.  Here's a complete demonstration:

```
~/ftptest$ find .    # Test folder with a number of files and directories in it.
.
./dir1
./dir1/subdir1
./dir1/subdir1/subsubfile1
./dir1/subfile1
./dir2
./file1
./file2

~/ftptest$ lftp localhost    # Connect
Password:
lftp blahdiblah@localhost:~> cd ~/ftptest/    # cd to test folder
cd ok, cwd=/Users/blahdiblah/ftptest

lftp blahdiblah@localhost:~ftptest> ls    # The files are there...
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  4 blahdiblah  staff  136 Jul 30 15:40 dir1
drwxr-xr-x  2 blahdiblah  staff   68 Jul 30 15:40 dir2
-rw-r--r--  1 blahdiblah  staff    0 Jul 30 15:40 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 blahdiblah  staff    0 Jul 30 15:40 file2

lftp blahdiblah@localhost:~/ftptest> glob -a rm -r *    # the magic happens...
rm ok, 7 files removed

lftp blahdiblah@localhost:~/ftptest> bye
~/ftptest$ find .    # ...and then they're gone!
.
~/ftptest$
```

[The docs](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) give the complete explanation:

> **rm** [**-r**] [**-f**] *files*
>
> Remove remote files.  Does not expand wildcards, use **mrm** for that. -r is for recursive directory remove.  Be careful, if something goes wrong you can lose files. -f suppress error messages.
>
> **glob** [**-d**] [**-a**] [**-f**] *command patterns*
>
> Glob  given patterns containing metacharacters and pass result to given command.  E.g.
>   `glob echo *`
>
> -f   plain files (default)
>   -d   directories
>   -a   all types

(Note that `mrm` isn't usable in this case because it doesn't expand `*` to include directories as well.)

Comment: Looks like lftp isn't compatible with a Windows server? That's what I'm running.

Comment: @MikeC. Poking around, I see some builds of lftp for Windows, as well as instructions for building it with Cygwin, so it should still be an option for you, but would be some extra work.

Answer (score 4):

Login in ftp server with
ncftp -u [user.ftp] [backup.server]

Run command

> rmdir -r [folder]

Answer (score 1):

To address OP's question directly, following command does exactly what is requested:

```
rm -r *
```

Make sure you navigate to the directory which contents you want to delete and issue the command. It removes all directories inside of the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash script that performs the delete.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script for retrieving all files on a an ftp server then deleting them.
#
# Requires ncftp and stock ftp client.
#
# We have to do some funkyness since there is no easy way of recursively deleting
#   remote directories.  We use ncftp to download all files and delete them on successfull
#   download. This ,however, leaves empty directories.  So we download the empty directory
#   tree to FSTREEDIR to list all directories to delete(we can't trust the download directory
#   because other directories may exist there). Those directories are then passed to the
#   usual ftp client to delete. 

# @todo - store credentials in a file

FTPSERVER=10.0.1.150
DOWNLOADDIR=/tmp/dl
FSTREEDIR=$DOWNLOADDIR/fstree
USERNAME=bart
PASSWORD=dude
DELETEREMOTEFILES=1


if [ $DELETEREMOTEFILES -eq 1 ]
 then
  DELFILESFLAG="-DD"
 else
  DELFILESFLAG=""
fi

echo "Downloading Reports...
"

cd $DOWNLOADDIR
ncftpget -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD -R $DELFILESFLAG ftp://$FTPSERVER


# Delete Files after download
if [ $DELETEREMOTEFILES -eq 1 ]
 then
    echo "Deleting Remote Reports...
    "

    RMSTRING=""

    # if fstree dir exists empty it and recreate it
    if [ ! -d "$FSTREEDIR" ]; then 
      mkdir $FSTREEDIR
    else
      rm -rf $FSTREEDIR/*
    fi

    # Copy remote directory structure to FSTREEDIR
    cd $FSTREEDIR
    ncftpget -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD -R $DELFILESFLAG ftp://$FTPSERVER

    # Generate list of directories to delete
    for D in `find $FSTREEDIR -type d| sort -r`
    do
      if [ ! "$D" = "$FSTREEDIR" ]; then
        RMSTRING="$RMSTRING 
        rmdir ${D#$FSTREEDIR/}"
      fi
    done

# Delete remote file structure
ftp -i -n <<EOF
open $FTPSERVER
user $USERNAME $PASSWORD
$RMSTRING
EOF

    # delete old FSTREEDIR
    rm -rf $FSTREEDIR

fi
```

Comment: I'm running a windows server so I'd prefer something a little more native.